# How to run a specific node.js unit test, using test.py?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run the [node.js unit tests](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/test), on Windows. I can run them all using either `vcbuild.bat test`, or `python ./tools/test.py`. Either of those commands will run all available tests. I'm writing my own test and just want to run it. How can I run a specific test file, using `test.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being as simple as running the file with the compiled node binary. Simply `node path\to\test.js`.